# Doorman asking to go see someone?

Tags: tiny-tower

I have the door man saying "I've been getting complaints about the smell from jacob crawfords apartement, I need to ask him some question!"

But when I press continue nothing happens!?  What do I do?  Skip, but I would like to figure out what you are suppose to do?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to locate that bitzen in your tower. Scroll through your tower to find him and tap on that individual to complete the quest for a tower bux.